# Set dropdownlist default value with a "td" value in grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid, dropdown

I have got a bit complicated problem, I have a grid each rows has a button to edit, when you click on the button a pop-up editor shows up to edit the row, in that pop up menu there is a drop down list, which has a list of all possible "product names", but the problem is when this pop up editor prompts, the drop down list selected value is different from the value of the respective "product name" value is the row, how can I make my dropdown list be set according the value in its respective cell value (first name) in the row.

```
 columns: [
     { field: 'Productname', title: 'Product name',width: '100px', editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor},
     { field: 'Password', title: 'Producer', width: '80px' },
     { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" }],
     editable: "popup",
});


function ProductNameDropDownEditor(container, options) {  

    $('<input  name="ProductName" data-type="string" \">')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: mydata,
            dataTextField: "Text",

        });                     

}
```

Comment: @Sinto its totally irrelevant with what I asked :))))

Comment: Add `dataValueField: "Text"` to yor dropdown editor options

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych I did it,but still in the pop up editor I see all fields in their respective text box,but I don't see this one(product name)selected by dropdownlist,I can also sen you the screen shot if you want

Comment: take a look at  [this DoJo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UPuWA) example

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych you survived me!!greatttt hep